# How can I add additional information from a post object to register a user in passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, passport.js

I am trying to register a user through passport-local with the following snippet:

```
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true  
}));
```

I am using a user model which apart from the data sending through the post method, I would like to add a "userCreated" and "lastAccess" Date property. They are already defined on the user model, but, how can I add these two variables to the post information, and then pass it to passport to create the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For anyone stumbling here I managed to do this by modifying the passport/signup.js file. You can personalize it to suit your needs.